# What can I do about this PickedFile error?

Tags: flutter

I get this error, what can I do about it?

```
A value of type 'PickedFile?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PickedFile'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'PickedFile'.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: the imagePicker() function returns PickedFile? that can be null, so change PickedFile picture to PickedFile? picture, and make sure to check if its not null with if (picture != null) images.add(picture!);

Comment: Acquaint yourself with the real understanding on Dart null safety. Once you understand the concept, you can straight away tell why you get these kinds of issues and can immediately fix them.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are assigning a nullable type (`PickedFile?`) to a non-nullable type (`PickedFile`).

What you can do:

### Make it nullable

If it is fine to use a nullable type, just make `picture` nullable:

```dart
void _openCamera() async {
  PickedFile? picture = await ImagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  images.add(picture);
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

#### Use the null-check operator

If you are sure that `ImagePicker.getImage()` is not going to return `null`, you can use the null-check operator (`!`).

```dart
void _openCamera() async {
  PickedFile picture = await ImagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera)!; // <- Notice the `!`
  images.add(picture);
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

### Make it nullable and filter it if it is `null`

If `ImagePicker.getImage()` can return `null` and you don't want your `images` list to contain null values. You can make it nullable and filter it if it is `null`:

```dart
void _openCamera() async {
  PickedFile? picture = await ImagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (picture != null) {
    images.add(picture);
  }
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// You can use this code hope this will work for you, Thanks

    final picker = ImagePicker();
    ///pop-up to choose camera gallery while selecting image
      Future<void> _showChoiceDialog(BuildContext context) {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text(
                  "Choose option",
                  style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),
                ),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: [
                      Divider(
                        height: 1,
                        color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context, _pickImage(ImageSource.gallery,context));
                        },
                        title: Text(
                          "Gallery",
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),
                        ),
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.account_box,
                          color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        height: 1,
                        color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context, _pickImage(ImageSource.camera,context));
                        },
                        title: Text(
                          "Camera",
                          style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue,),
                        ),
                        leading: Icon(
                          Icons.camera,
                          color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    
     ///ImageSource: Camera and Gallery.
      Future<Null> _pickImage(ImageSource source,context) async {
        final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
        _image = pickedImage != null ? File(pickedImage.path) : null;
        if (_image != null) {
          setState(() {
          });}}

////call this method 
GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
_showChoiceDialog(context);},
```